# VSTO Can't Read App.Config

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

After deploying a VSTO Excel Add-In I am unable to read the app.config file.

My question is identical to this one:

[VSTO Debug version fine, Installed version doesn't read app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586875/vsto-debug-version-fine-installed-version-doesnt-read-app-config)

Except, when I change the registry entry to use the `file:///` as suggested in the post I get the following error:

> The common language runtime could not be loaded by file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\company\product\addin.vsto|vstolocal. Contact your administrator for further assistance.

Without using `file:///` the Add-In loads fine but doesn't read the configuration file.

I am using the following software:

- Excel 2010 (installed - 32bit)
- VSTO 2010 (10.0.60724 - 64bit)
- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- .NET (4.6.00081)

The link here says that based on my software I needed to install the 64bit of VSTO:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I tried to install .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 but as 4.6 is installed it won't continue. 4.6 is required by the add-in.

Is there something I am missing that is required to get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure that there is not another addin, loading a different version of .Net? The first one loaded wins and your 4.6 one might not be the one loaded first.

Comment: Nope, fresh VM built specifically to test this add-in. Nothing else on the box.

Comment: Just a thought, had it happen to me..but I believe that situation got resolved after a certain VSTO version.

Comment: Thanks, I believe 10.0.60724 is the latest version though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this. The problem was that InstallShield does not contain a prerequisite of .NET 4.6.1 yet and so the developer had selected .NET 4.6 instead, however when the Add-In loads it looks for the exact version of .NET it requires which was not part of the installation.

To resolve, I removed .NET 4.6 and installed 4.6.1 manually.

Comment: As an aside...your original post said you were using .Net 4.6...and not 4.6.1. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I was told by the developer, it was only when I looked at the registry keys that I saw 4.6.1, thus leading to the actual underlying problem. Thank you for your help though. :)